# Redirect 301 if paged url not found Nginx

Tags: nginx

I would like to 301 redirect a URL which contains /page/ keyword to non /page/ version if not found with try_files directive.

e.g. example.com/x-y-z/page/186/ to example.com/x-y-z/
example.com/page/2020/ to example.com

Answer (score 0):

This works well.

```
 location ~ "(.*/)page/.*$" {    
          set $redirect_paged_url $1;
          try_files $uri $uri/ @redirect_paged_not_found;
          }

 location @redirect_paged_not_found {
         add_header X-Redirect-By myRedirectRule;
         return 301 https://$host$redirect_paged_url;
         }  
    
  location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;                  
         }
```